# How to create a variable in powershell for get-netroute to input current environment settings

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

So I have a bit of a complex question that maybe i'm not entirely sure how to ask, but I want to use the `Get-Netroute` command to grab the current machines default gateway and input it into the same command and then add it as a route as shown below. The issue is I need to run this on instances in AWS on many different subnets with many different default gateways so I need the gateway to auto-populate in the `route-add` command. I was able to make a variable for the default gateway, but the issue is that the `get-netroute` command changes the `-interfaceindex` and `-routemetric` tabs by instance so I need variables for both. I'm open to using other commands I just tend to gravitate towards commands that are not too complex and can be done in 1 line.

```
`$defaultgatway = Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex 5 -RouteMetric 0 | Select-Object NextHop

route -p ADD 169.254.169.254 MASK 255.255.255.255 $defaultgatway.NextHop

route -p ADD 169.254.169.251 MASK 255.255.255.255 $defaultgatway.NextHop

route -p ADD 169.254.169.250 MASK 255.255.255.255 $defaultgatway.NextHop`
```

This is the error I get when I try to run this script as is on the values of another machine, it worked fine on the original machine that I made it on: `

```
Get-NetRoute : No matching MSFT_NetRoute objects found by CIM query for 
instances of the ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetRoute class on the  CIM server: 
SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetRoute  WHERE ((InterfaceIndex = 5)) AND ((RouteMetric = 
0)). Verify query parameters and retry.
At line:1 char:18
+ $defaultgatway = Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex 5 -RouteMetric 0 | Select-Object 
N ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetRoute:String) [Get-NetRou 
   te], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Get-NetRoute
 
route : 
At line:3 char:1
+ route -p ADD 169.254.169.254 MASK 255.255.255.255 $defaultgatway.NextHop
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError`
```

I guess my overall question is how do I get the data to put in those variables what command do I use if not this one? I know how to make a variable in a general sense for sure.

Comment: You might want to try `Get-NetIPConfiguration` instead. If there's just 1 NIC that'll get you the interface number and the gateway. If you have more than one NIC you may need to do something like `Get-NetIPConfiguration | where{$_.IPv4DefaultGateway}` to get the right one.

Comment: it looks like there is only 1 default gateway listing when i use that command. so i would just do like Get-NetIPconfiguration -IPv4DefaultGateway and then input that tag into the route command?

Comment: Do just like you are now `$defaultgatway = Get-NetIPConfiguration` then `New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 169.254.169.254/32 -NextHop $defaultgatway.IPv4DefaultGateway -PolicyStore PersistentStore -InterfaceIndex $defaultGateway.InterfaceIndex`

Comment: that command isnt the same one i used so im a bit confused, im just using route -p

Comment: That is the PowerShell cmdlet that is used for adding routes. You can use `route -p add` if you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: why does it give me a bunch of gibberish when i `select-object ipv4defaultgateway` from the `get-netipconfiguration` command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235951/discussion-between-dpw808-and-themadtechnician).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the default gateway with `Get-NetIpConfiguration`, and then use that in your `route -p add` commands. Since the gateway that `Get-NetIpConfiguration` returns is the full CIM instance of the default gateway route you'll need to specify the `NextHop` property. To do that you would end up with this:

```
$defaultgatway = Get-NetIPConfiguration
route -p ADD 169.254.169.254 MASK 255.255.255.255 $defaultgateway.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
route -p ADD 169.254.169.251 MASK 255.255.255.255 $defaultgateway.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
route -p ADD 169.254.169.250 MASK 255.255.255.255 $defaultgateway.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
```